# Need help writing a custom BuildListener

Tags: eclipse, ant, eclipse-plugin

I would like to add a BuildListener to my headless build process, which is building an Eclipse product. The docs on how to do this are, shall we say, a bit scanty. I think I need to put my custom jar in a plugin and then use the org.eclipse.ant.core.extraClasspathEntries extension point to make that jar visible to Ant. But everything I have tried results in

```
 [myClass] which was specified to be a build listener is not an instance of org.apache.tools.ant.BuildListener.
```

My class implements the BuildListener interface. Various  postings seem to indicate that this means my class is visible-to/loaded-by the Plugin classloader rather than the Ant classloader. But I thought the whole point of the extension point was to make jars visible to Ant...

Can anyone shed light on what I'm doing wrong?
Additional info: I am trying to run this build from the Eclipse IDE at the moment using the AntRunner application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem when I had two plugins providing an `ant.jar`.

Make sure you use the `org.apache.ant` plugin and that there is no other plugin providing another `ant.jar`.

Another thing I just stumbled upon: The jar containing your contribution must not be in the plugins classpath (Runtime -> Classpath).

See [Eclipse Bug 34466](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=34466).

Comment: Thanks. I had already solved this, but this was indeed the problem. You must be very scrupulous about the location of the contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions as for working with contributed tasks and types found here:
[Developing Ant tasks](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ant_developing.htm) and [Contributed Ant tasks](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ant_contributing_task.htm)